# Is there any authentic hadith that the complete Salawat is " اللهم صل علی محمد و آل محمد" ? (Sunni view)

Tags: hadith, sunni, authenticity, salawat

I know it is the belief of Shia that we must recite the complete Salawat (صلوات) as follow:

> **اللهم صل علی محمد و آل محمد**
>
> It is factually a formula of praise and greetings to Allah (The
>   Prophet and his descendants)

But is there any authentic Hadith (Sunni view) that the perfect Salawat is with "**و آل محمد**" ?

I mean:

**اللهم صل علی محمد و آل محمد؟**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several ways that Prophet Mohamed (pbuh) had taught the Muslims on how to do salawat and what to say.

Some are as followed:

> حَدَّثَنِي سَعِيدُ بْنُ يَحْيَى، حَدَّثَنَا أَبِي، حَدَّثَنَا
>   مِسْعَرٌ، عَنِ الْحَكَمِ، عَنِ ابْنِ أَبِي لَيْلَى، عَنْ كَعْبِ بْنِ
>   عُجْرَةَ ـ رضى الله عنه ـ قِيلَ يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ، أَمَّا السَّلاَمُ
>   عَلَيْكَ فَقَدْ عَرَفْنَاهُ فَكَيْفَ الصَّلاَةُ قَالَ ‏ "‏ قُولُوا
>   اللَّهُمَّ صَلِّ عَلَى مُحَمَّدٍ وَعَلَى آلِ مُحَمَّدٍ، كَمَا
>   صَلَّيْتَ عَلَى آلِ إِبْرَاهِيمَ، إِنَّكَ حَمِيدٌ مَجِيدٌ، اللَّهُمَّ
>   بَارِكْ عَلَى مُحَمَّدٍ وَعَلَى آلِ مُحَمَّدٍ، كَمَا بَارَكْتَ عَلَى
>   آلِ إِبْرَاهِيمَ، إِنَّكَ حَمِيدٌ مَجِيدٌ ‏"‏‏.‏
>
> Narrated Ka'b bin Ujra: It was said, "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! We know
>   how to greet you, but how to invoke Allah for you?" The Prophet said,
>   "Say: Allahumma salli ala Muhammadin wa'ala `Ali Muhammaddin, kama
>   sallaita 'ala all Ibrahim, innaka Hamidun Majid."
>
> [[Sahih Bukhari]](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/80/57)

Another:

> حَدَّثَنَا إِبْرَاهِيمُ بْنُ حَمْزَةَ، حَدَّثَنَا ابْنُ أَبِي حَازِمٍ،
>   وَالدَّرَاوَرْدِيُّ، عَنْ يَزِيدَ، عَنْ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ خَبَّابٍ،
>   عَنْ أَبِي سَعِيدٍ الْخُدْرِيِّ، قَالَ قُلْنَا يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ
>   هَذَا السَّلاَمُ عَلَيْكَ، فَكَيْفَ نُصَلِّي قَالَ ‏ "‏ قُولُوا
>   اللَّهُمَّ صَلِّ عَلَى مُحَمَّدٍ عَبْدِكَ وَرَسُولِكَ، كَمَا صَلَّيْتَ
>   عَلَى إِبْرَاهِيمَ، وَبَارِكْ عَلَى مُحَمَّدٍ وَعَلَى آلِ مُحَمَّدٍ،
>   كَمَا بَارَكْتَ عَلَى إِبْرَاهِيمَ وَآلِ إِبْرَاهِيمَ ‏"‏‏.‏
>
> Narrated Abu Sa'id Al-Khudri: We said, "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) This
>   is (i.e. we know) the greeting to you; will you tell us how to send
>   Salat on you?" He said, "Say: 'Allahumma Salli 'ala Muhammadin 'Abdika
>   wa rasulika kama sal-laita 'ala Ibrahima wa barik 'ala Muhammadin wa
>   all Muhammadin kama barakta 'ala Ibrahima wa `Ali Ibrahim."
>
> [[Sahih Bukhari]](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/80/55)

And another one:

> حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ اللَّهِ بْنُ مَسْلَمَةَ، عَنْ مَالِكٍ، عَنْ عَبْدِ
>   اللَّهِ بْنِ أَبِي بَكْرٍ، عَنْ أَبِيهِ، عَنْ عَمْرِو بْنِ سُلَيْمٍ
>   الزُّرَقِيِّ، قَالَ أَخْبَرَنِي أَبُو حُمَيْدٍ السَّاعِدِيُّ،
>   أَنَّهُمْ قَالُوا يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ كَيْفَ نُصَلِّي عَلَيْكَ قَالَ ‏
>   "‏ قُولُوا اللَّهُمَّ صَلِّ عَلَى مُحَمَّدٍ وَأَزْوَاجِهِ
>   وَذُرِّيَّتِهِ، كَمَا صَلَّيْتَ عَلَى آلِ إِبْرَاهِيمَ، وَبَارِكْ
>   عَلَى مُحَمَّدٍ وَأَزْوَاجِهِ وَذُرِّيَّتِهِ، كَمَا بَارَكْتَ عَلَى
>   آلِ إِبْرَاهِيمَ، إِنَّكَ حَمِيدٌ مَجِيدٌ ‏"‏‏.‏
>
> Narrated Abu Humaid As-Saidi: The people said, "O Allah's Messenger
>   (ﷺ) ! How may we send Salat on you?" He said, "Say: Allahumma Salli
>   'ala- Muhammadin wa azwajihi wa dhurriyyatihi kama sal-laita 'ala 'Ali
>   Ibrahim; wa barik 'ala Muhammadin wa azwajihi wa dhurriyyatihi
>   kamabarakta 'ala `Ali Ibrahim innaka hamidun majid."
>
> [[Sahih Bukhari]](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/80/57)

And these are just three different ways authentically reported.

Comment: first link is wrong

Comment: the first link works now